# How can I add responsiveness to "collect" div which apply 20px padding for right and left side under 992px width

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="collect">
    <img class="price-icon" src="images/price.png" alt="priceicon">
    <input class="price" type="number" min="0.10" step="0.01" placeholder="Price of a Lot">

    <img class="number-icon" src="images/number.png" alt="numbericon">
    <input class="number" type="number" min="1" step="1" placeholder="Number of Lots">

    <button onclick="createTable()" class="calculate">Calculate</button>
</div>
```

I expect that for example in 400px screen on the left and right side of the screen will be 20px padding. So division is not adjacent with the left and right side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can use @media rule in css.
Insert code to your css file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .collect {
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
  }
}
```